# How to have a Joomla module on top of another module

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jhtml

Is it possible to have a module on top of another module? If so how would I go about doing this. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the 2 modules to the same position?

Comment: Yes I have but it just goes underneath the first module. I am wanting to have the first module as a white background and then text on the second module. So basically the text will be on a white background.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not simply have a white background with text on 1 module?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work that way so I am wanting to do the 2 modules on top of each other. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I'll put this as an answer so I can go into further detail.

So you basically need a module with a white background and text on top of it. You initially wanted to have 2 modules. 1 on top of the other. Simply fact is that this is a bad approach and not required at all.

To suit your needs, you only need 1 module, so go to your Module Manager, create a **new** module and set the type to **Custom**. Once done, you will see a field called **Module Class Suffix**. Type in something which will act as a CSS class. For example `white`.

**Note: Make sure you put a space before the word**

Once done, open the CSS file for your template and add the following code:

```
.white {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

This will make the background for your module white an d the colour of the text black. You can of course add additional styling to suit your needs.

Hope this helps